# Java UNIXProcess not visible in Eclipse?

Tags: java, constructor, mocking, visibility

I tried to use the UNIXProcess.class, but the eclipse keeps warning me that UNIXProcess is not visible.

The code is simple:

```
import java.lang.Process;

public class Simple {

   UNIXProcess process;

}
```

Can anyone know to use the UNIXProcess?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.lang.UNIXProcess` is declared as default visibility which means that it cannot be seen by classes outside of the package `java.lang.*`. Use `ProcessBuilder` or `Runtime.exec()`, instead, to create a valid `Process` object.